# How can I measure wealth gain (loss) due to inequality?

Tags: inflation, theory

As time passes, outside of inflation, the buying power of an individual changes relative to their peers wealth.

How can I measure the effect wealth inequality has relative to one's savings?

Comment: I want to tag this `gini-coefficient` but I don't have sufficient rep. Please edit as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Economists generally think of three similar, but distinct, metrics of economic disparity: inequality of income, consumption and wealth. Income inequality is the most commonly cited measure, consumption inequality, though harder to measure, provides a better proxy of social welfare. Wealth is also an important metric since it can be inherited, unlike income. Most people would use the Gini coefficients to measure all three.

This [article](https://www.equalitytrust.org.uk/how-economic-inequality-defined) might be of use.